# only last four entries of .ts files found in out.m3u8 file when I am using ffmpeg to convert mp4 to m3u8 format why

Tags: ffmpeg, m3u8

When I am using following command to convert .mp4 15 second video to .m3u8 format with hls_time 1 it convert in 15 .ts files using ffmpeg after successful conversation but when open the out.m3u8 file I Found only last four .ts file in out.m3u8 instead of 15 .ts files entries, please help what should I do for getting all 15 files in out.m3u8

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:v h264 -flags +cgop -g 30 -hls_time 1 out.m3u8`

Answer (score 4):

The HLS muxer defaults to creating a playlist with a sliding window of `hls_list_size` items (default: 5).

To keep all segments you can set the output parameter `hls_playlist_type` to either `vod` or `event` depending on your use case, which forces the `hls_list_size` to 0 (keep all segments). In your case you need `vod`.

The documentation can be found [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-2).

Comment: thanks for this, due to some misunderstanding, I am doing with different way, but after your suggestion I am on a write way.